# Cakephp updating associated inputs creates duplicated records

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have two tables that are related strategies and strategy_conditions. Strategies can have many strategy_conditions.

I have updated the strategies `add.php` with some javascript so that I can add strategy_conditions to the same page   etc. All works great.

I want to be able to edit the strategies_conditions at the same time on the strategies `edit.php` I can loop over and add the correct associated strategies_conditions inputs with the their values but my issue is that rather than update the `strategies_conditions` it creates new records. Strange because cakephp recognises the details because it has the right values in the inputs.

here is the cakephp code inside strategies `edit.php` template

```
<?php foreach ($strategy->strategies_conditions as $key=>$strategiesConditions) : ?>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <?php echo $this->Form->control('strategies_conditions.'.$key.'.name', array( 'label' => false )); ?>
          </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to edit associated records, then you *must* also supply the primary key for those records.

For the parent the primary key is not necessarily needed, as it is usually being passed in the URL (ie `/strategies/edit/1`), and used to obtain the parent entity that is being patched with the form data.

For the associated records however there is no such data anywhere else, so you need to explicitly pass it alongside the rest of the record's data, so that the marhshaller can identify and patch the existing entities/records, otherwise you will end up with new entities without primary key, eg new records.

Assuming the primary key is `id`:

```php
echo $this->Form->hidden('strategies_conditions.' . $key . '.id');
echo $this->Form->control('strategies_conditions.' . $key . '.name', array(
    'label' => false
));
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Patching HasMany and BelongsToMany](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/saving-data.html#patching-hasmany-and-belongstomany)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Inputs for Associated Data](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Hidden Inputs](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-hidden-inputs)**

Comment: thank you, I missed that in the cookbook, I have a better understanding after your reply